# Is there a way to save raw opencv images to video?

Tags: python, opencv, pywin32

I'm pretty new to opencv and I've been trying to build an automatic stat tracker for a game I'm playing. I want to collect videos to test the object recognition and stat tracking code, and thought I might as well use the capture code I've already written to make the test videos. So I've been using the pywin32 api to make images for opencv to process, and thought I'd just directly use those images to save to video.

The problem I'm having is that the videos being made are invalid and useless.

So now that I've gone through the background I can move on to the actual questions.

Is there a specific format the opencv images need to be in before they can be saved? or is there a way to possibly feed the images through the VideoCapture class in a non clunky way (like recapturing the cv.imshow window)? I don't want to directly use the VideoCapture class, because it requires the specified window to be always on top. I might also just be doing it wrong.

Code included below.

```
class VideoScreenCapture:
    frame_time_limit = 0
    time_elapsed = 0
    frame_width = None
    frame_height = None
    frame_size = None
    fps = None
    window_capture = None
    filming = False
    output_video = None
    scaling_factor = 2/3

    def __init__(self, window_capture=None, fps=5):
        """
        window_capture: a custom window capture object that is associated with the window to be captured
        fps: the frames per second of the resulting video
        """
        self.fps = fps
        # calculate the amount of time per frame (inverse of fps)
        self.frame_time_limit = 1/self.fps

        self.window_capture = window_capture
        # get the size (in pixels) of the window getting captured
        self.frame_width, self.frame_height, self.frame_size = self.window_capture.get_frame_dimentions()

        # initialize video writer
        self.output_video = cv.VideoWriter(
            f'assets{sep}Videos{sep}test.avi',
            cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
            self.fps,
            self.frame_size)

    def update(self, dt):
        """dt: delta time -> the time since the last update"""
        # only updates if the camera is on
        if self.filming:
            # update the elapsed time
            self.time_elapsed += dt
            
            # if the elapsed time is more than the time segment calculated for the given fps
            if self.time_elapsed >= self.frame_time_limit:
                self.time_elapsed -= self.frame_time_limit
                
                # window capture takes screenshot of the capture window and resizes it to the wanted side
                frame = self.window_capture.get_screenshot()
                frame = cv.resize(
                    frame,
                    dsize=(0, 0),
                    fx=self.scaling_factor,
                    fy=self.scaling_factor)
                # the image is then saved to video
                self.output_video.write(frame)
                
                # show the image in a separate window
                cv.imshow("Computer Vision", frame)
    
    """methods for stopping and starting the video capture"""
    def start(self):
        self.filming = True

    def stop(self):
        self.filming = False
    
    """releases video writer: use when done""" 
    def release_vw(self):
        self.output_video.release()
```

This while loop that runs the code

```
    vsc.start()
    loop_time = time()
    while cv.waitKey(1) != ord('q'):
        vsc.update(time() - loop_time)
        loop_time = time()
```

Comment: OpenCV's VideoCapture *reads* from a file or video device. what could you possibly mean by "because it requires the specified window to be always on top"?

Comment: OpenCV's VideoWriter requires that you give it a frame size at initialization **and** that every frame you give it is exactly that size. check this.

Comment: you should work to present a [mre]. currently your code contains a lot of stuff that seems beside the point.

Comment: You can in fact initialize VideoCapture with an int index instead of filename. Then you can use it to capture the frames from a video stream or a camera. Many of the methods of doing screen capture in python (manly PIL and pyautogui which uses the PIL api anyway) take from the output going to a monitor which means you can't have the image being captured either minimized or covered by other windows. The frame is set by the window capture and never changes.

Comment: that's a limitation of screen capture. you should not expect there to be a way around this situation. on windows, there might be a way... it involves accessing the full-resolution "thumbnail" of the window, which is also used in the taskbar. I don't think those windows update when they're minimized but it would let you capture the full unobscured window even when it is not topmost.